# SQL Classify table using a "from-to"

Tags: sql, google-analytics, analytics

I have a table which has 3 dimensions and 2 metrics (for instance, just one of many)

The table is something like:

[image]

And I have this other table, which helps to classify:

[image]

And the final result should be:

[image]

This problem has been haunting me for the last SIX MONTHS

Could someone help me?

Please, find example data [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1frec-FQ7Uin0ZSnDTUVyuNtV_Ebov2QS_amKTqjcEQQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below sql:

```
SELECT A.dt,A.source,A.compaing,A.sessions,A.pageviews,
CASE WHEN B.value IS NULL THEN
     'Unknown'
ELSE 
      B.value
END Vehicle, 
CASE WHEN C.value IS NULL THEN
     'Unknown'
ELSE 
     C.value
END Effort
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B ON B.from='source' AND A.source like '%' + B.pattern + '%'
LEFT JOIN table2 C ON C.from='campaign' AND A.compaing like '%' + C.pattern
```

Comment: Hello Dinesh, thanks for your reply. I am not sure whether it is possible to do a "LIKE" inside the "ON" clause on other databases, but in Bigquery (which I am using) it is not possible. Also, the query does not cover when no match is found, in which case the "Unknown" value should be assigned, instead of throwing the lines off. Anyway, I am very glad about your response.

Comment: You can use left join instead of inner join for including 'Unknown' cases. I have updated my above SQL for the same.